# Explicación del metodo de interface sort.swap en go

Tags: go

Estoy haciendo un [tutorial](http://www.goconejemplos.com/ordenamiento-por-funciones) de go y me encontré con el siguiente ejemplo de ordenamiento por funciones:

```
package main
import "sort"
import "fmt"
type ByLength []string
func (s ByLength) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}
func (s ByLength) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] //Aqui las dudas
}
func (s ByLength) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return len(s[i]) < len(s[j])
}
func main() {
    fruits := []string{"peach", "banana", "kiwi"}
    sort.Sort(ByLength(fruits))
    fmt.Println(fruits)
}
```

Aunque entiendo las funciones `Less` y `Len`, no logro entender la sintaxis de la función `Swap` ¿Porqué no tiene return?¿Si es una asignación multiple regresa 3 valores?¿Si esto `s[j] = s[j]` compara o asigna, que no siempre queda igual?
¿Alguien podría responderme todas estas dudas?
Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La intención de la función `Swap` es la de intercambiar los valores entre dos posiciones del *array*

> ¿Por qué no tiene `return`?

Porque no devuelve ningún valor, puede decirse que es un procedimiento.  La función misma no declara tipo de retorno `func (s ByLength) Swap(i, j int) {` no tiene un tipo luego de la declaración de los parámetros.  Es útil solo para cambiar la posición de los elementos.

> ¿Si es una asignación multiple regresa 3 valores?

```
 s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
```

Esto es una asignación simultanea, si tenemos las variables `a` y `b`, la asignación ocurre de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la posición `i` del *array* ahora va a tener el valor de la posición `j` y viceversa.  En otros lenguajes de programación normalmente se haría de esta manera:

```
aux = s[i]
s[i] = s[j]
s[j] = aux
```

Comment: Gracias, esta era la explicación que necesitaba.

Answer (score 2):

Si te fijas en la documentación del paquete ["sort"](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#StringSlice.Swap) te darás cuenta que esta versión de Swap es un "metodo" implementado para el tipo StringSlice, el cual no es más que un []string, es decir un slice de strings, en el paquete sort tambien hay implementaciones de este metodo para otros tipos.

En la definición de la función puede ver que este metodo opera sobre "s"

```
func (s ByLength) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i] //Aqui las dudas
}
```

"s" es un slice de strings, en este caso : `[]string{"peach", "banana", "kiwi"}`

Swap es una funcion utilizada por Sort(data Interface) para realizar el ordenamiento intercambiando sucesivamente de lugar los strings  en las posiciones i y j

En golang, asi como en muchos otros lenguajes las funciones no necesariamente deben devolver un valor.

Te dejo otro ejemplo de métodos en golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Prueba int

func (p *Prueba) Sum(i Prueba) {
    *p += Prueba(i)
}

func main() {
    prueba := Prueba(1) // prueba es de tipo Prueba y es inicializado con el valor 1
    prueba.Sum(1)       // a prueba le sumamos 1
    prueba.Sum(1)       // a prueba le sumamos 1
    fmt.Println(prueba) // prueba = 3
}
```

Pruebalo aqui:
http://play.golang.org/p/jPbSm_WVb8